# Symfony custom form weird property access errors

Tags: symfony

I've got this strange problem, here is example usage of my custom ThingType class.

```
->add('photos', 'namespace\Form\Type\ThingType', [
    'required' => false,
])
```

if the field name is `photos` everything works as expected, but if I change my entity field to let's say `photosi`, run generate entities, and change the form field name, this error is thrown:

> Neither the property "photosi" nor one of the methods
>   "addPhotosus()"/"removePhotosus()", "setPhotosi()", "photosi()",
>   "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class
>   "AppBundle\Entity\Product".

I guess the problem comes from Symfony trying to generate getter method name for my entity. Why is this `addPhotosus` method name generated? How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

I'm using model transformer when showing the data to the user.

```
    $builder->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function ($imagesAsText) {
            if (!$imagesAsText) {
                return null;
            }

            $newImages = [];
            foreach($imagesAsText as $img) {
                $newImages[] = $img->getID();
            }

            return implode(',', $newImages);
        },
        function ($textAsImages) use ($repo) {
            $images = [];
            foreach(explode(',', $textAsImages) as $imgID) {
                $img = $repo->findOneById($imgID);

                if ($img) {
                    $images[] = $img;
                }
            }

            return $images;
        }
    ));
```

The actual field is TextType::class with entity ids in it for example `1,10,32,51`. The model transformer transforms this data to entities. Setting 'data_class' to my form type seems irrelevant, because the actual form type is a part of entity. I mean I have `Product` entity and `Photo` entity, `photos` is array of `photo` entity. So in my ThingType, what `data_class` should I use, `photo` or `product`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fist parameter of the add method for a form, should be one of the mapped attributes of the data_class of the form, usually selected inside the form as

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Product'
        ));
}
```

That isn't related to the form name. So , you are trying to access to a "photosi" attribute inside your Product class.

Hope this help you.

Comment: And you can add a 'mapped'=>false if you want this child to not be mappe.

Comment: I'm using TextType::class to keep array of entities, transformed by modelTransformer and this error shows when I try to set 'data_class'
`The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Product, but is a(n) string`

Comment: @nacholibre Maybe you should update your question with some code, or make a new one , since it had nothing to do with this thread question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for the first point you need to remember that `Symfony` is looking for `setXX()` and `getXX()`method in your entity for each entry of your form.
If you change your variable name you need to update the form :

```php
->add('newName', XXType::class, [
    'required' => false,
])
```

and you're entity by changing the variable

```php
class Entity 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $newName;

    public function getOldName(){
        return $this->$oldName;
    }

   public function setOldName(oldName){
       $this->oldName = $oldName;
       return $this
   }

}
```

then run the command

```sh
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate
```

and symfony will upload your entity by itself

```
class Entity 
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @SerializedName("title")
     * @Groups({"calendar"})
     */
    private $newName;

    public function getOldName(){
        return $this->$oldName;
    }

   public function setOldName($oldName){
       $this->oldName = $oldName;
       return $this
   }

   public function getNewName(){
       return $this->newName;
   }

   public function setNewName($newName){
       $this->newName = $newName;
       return $this
   }
```

> note that the old `get` and `set` method are not deleted by the script
>
> note as well that in your specific case of `photosi`, `symfony`guess that the "i" is a plural mark and look for `addPhotosus()` methods

For the **edit** it looks very unclear and has nothing to do with the first question. Consider reading : [doc on collectionType](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/collections/embedded-form-collection)